# LaTeX makeindex with gind.ist style combined with hyperref package

Tags: latex, hyperref

I am currently having a problem with makeindex package and gind.ist style when combined with hyperref package with TeXnicCenter and LaTeX=>PDF conversion.

Without using gind.ist everything is fine, but as soon as I use gind.ist style I get lots of errors.

Did anybody face a similar problem and can suggest any solutions?

Alternatively, I need index with hyper references in PDF and explicit letter separation:

-- A --
a 10, 15, 178
abc 19, 20, 39
...

-- B -- 
...

etc.

Thanks a lot for suggestions.

Ovanes.

P.S. Please don't suggest slutions like: "use xindy" without any examples or references how it can replace makeindex package.

Comment: In re SuperUser: Go here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow to argue your case, but you appear to be out voted. LaTeX questions belong on StackOverflow

Comment: @ovanes: Describing the packages in questions might help. Particularly `gind.ist` which I have never heard of. Links are useful as well.

Comment: @dmckee: gind.ist is not a package, but a stylesheet delivered with makeindex package.

Comment: @ovanes: The usual thing to do, on finding your own solution is to post is as an answer... This sequence of actions as actively encouraged in the FAQ, and people may reward you with upvotes. There is even a badge if you get enough votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I have found a solution to this point, just after posting it here:

I created a custom style file with .ist extension and put this content inside:

```
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "      % insert in front of letter
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"  % append after letter
headings_flag  1                 % turn on headings(uppercase)
```

This code comes from this [wiki page](http://wiki.cds.caltech.edu/tex/makeindex), which is offline but is cached by [google](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:8Ogc2LVibzsJ:wiki.cds.caltech.edu/tex/makeindex+%22To+add+simple+Index+headings,+A,+B,+C,%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de&lr=lang_en).

Hope that will helps to others, since I spent some time to search for it.

Regards,
Ovanes